# How to make a responsive single page website with sidebar?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

What I am looking to do is create a website which has two sections - a left hand sidebar which will contain the name of the website/logo, the menu, and a small footer with copyright and maybe social links. The other section will be the main content of the site.

Really simply shown below, probably using 'display: inline-block'.

```
<html>
    <div class="sidebar">

    </div>

    <div class="content">

    </div>
</html>
```

[image]

Doing this without being responsive seems fairly straightforward, I could either set the sidebar to 20% width and the content to 80%. Or set the sidebar to a fixed width of say 500px and the content to 100% - 500px. But both of these seem like they could cause problems depending on the resoulution of the display.

Using percentages could result in a too tiny sidebar on smaller screens and a too big sidebar on bigger screens. So giving it a fixed width seems a better option, but then it could give an opposite problem of being too big on small screens, and too small on bigger screens.

Is there any sort of industry standard for building a website in this way? I have seen a few websites using this type of design (Mainly photographers and other portfolio style uses).

Comment: Look for "min-height" "max-height" and the same for width

Comment: That could work but once the sidebar reaches the minimum or maximum height, then the percentage based width of the content could mess up because the ratio will no longer be the same

Comment: Media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```css
#fixedWidth{ 
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
        background: blue;
}
#theRest{
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id=fixedWidth>Fixed</div>
<div id=theRest>The rest of the space<br>WTF?</div>
```

Comment: As simple as that is I think that might be exactly what I am looking for, after combining it with min-width and max-width as commented above!

Answer (score 2):

use @ media Query , here's a working example for using media Query to make a responsive sidebar

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.sidebar{
  height:100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #535F8D;
  color: #fff;
}
.main{
  background: #D0D6EF;
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
 .sidebar{
    min-height:100vh;
    float:left;
    width:300px;
  }
  .main{
    margin-left:300px;
    min-height:100vh;/* just for demo , you can delete it*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-wrapper">
 <div class="sidebar">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt assumenda numquam eligendi nihil quibusdam dolores similique expedita iure consectetur, molestias odit, ullam dolor id nemo, autem minima quisquam possimus facilis.
 </div>
 <div class="main">
  
 </div>
</div>
```